# Multi-threaded image processing program

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I'm receiving two errors:

1. 'Bitmap ImageManipulation.LockBits(object)' has the wrong return type
2. 'Bitmap ImageManipulation.GetSet(object)' has the wrong return type

And they point me to the problem as shown:
[image]

How can I change  public Bitmap LockBits and GetSet to have the correct return type?

Form1.cs

```
        Bitmap newFile;
        Bitmap[,] imgArray;
        Bitmap[,] modimgArray;

        ImageManipulation modifyRGB = new ImageManipulation();
        FileOperations getFile = new FileOperations();


        private void btnLockBits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(modifyRGB.LockBits));
            t1.Start(newFile);
        }




        private void btnGetSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            #region Call ImageManipulation Class
            // Set up thread(s) to run "Manipulatie" method
            //Use parameterized thread start

            //**********************************************
            // NOTE: method "manipulate" needs to accept type "object", not Bitmap in order
            // for it to work with parameterized thread start
            // **********************************************

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(modifyRGB.GetSet));
            t1.Start(newFile);
            #endregion

            //modifyRGB.Manipulate(newFile);

        }
```

ImageManipulation.cs

```
public class ImageEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
            public Bitmap bmap { get; set; }
    }




 public Bitmap GetSet(object bmp)
        {
            Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)bmp;
            Color theColor = new Color();

            for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    // Get the color of the pixel at (i, j)
                    theColor = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);

                    // Change the color at that pixel; DivideByZeroException out the green and blue
                    Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(theColor.R, theColor.G, 0);

                    // Set the new color of the pixel
                    bmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
                }
            }

            OnImageFinished(bmap);
            return bmap;
        }




 public Bitmap LockBits(object bmp)
        {
            Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)bmp;

            // Use "unsafe" becausae c# doesnt support pointer arithmetic by default
            unsafe
            {
                // Lock the bitmap into system memory
                // "Pixelformat" can be "Fomat24bppRgb", "Format32bppArgb", etc.
                BitmapData bitmapData =
                    bmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmap.Width,
                    bmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmap.PixelFormat);

                //Define variables for bytes per pixel, as well as Image Width & Height
                int bytesPerPixel = System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
                int heightInPixels = bitmapData.Height;
                int widthInBytes = bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel;

                //Define a pointer to the first pixel in the locked image
                // Scan0 gets or sets the address of the first pixel data in the bitmap
                // This can also be thought of as the first scan line in the bitmap.
                byte* PtrFirstPixel = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

                // Step through each pixel in the image using pointers
                // Parallel.For executes a 'for' loop in which iterations
                // may run in parralel
                Parallel.For(0, heightInPixels, y =>
                {

                    // USe the 'Stride' (scanline width) proerty to step line by line thru the image
                    byte* currentLine = PtrFirstPixel + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < widthInBytes; x = x + bytesPerPixel)
                    {

                        // GET: each pixel color (R, G, & B)
                        int oldBlue = currentLine[x];
                        int oldGreen = currentLine[x + 1];
                        int oldRed = currentLine[x + 2];

                        // SET: Zero out the Blue, copy Green and Red unchanged
                        currentLine[x] = 0;
                        currentLine[x + 1] = (byte)oldGreen;
                        currentLine[x + 2] = (byte)oldRed;
                    }

                });

                bmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
            OnImageFinished(bmap);
            return bmap;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `Thread` rather than `Task`?

Comment: You can use: `var newImage = await Task.Run(()=> ImageManipulation.LockBits([SomeBitmap]));`. You can make `LockBits` static - if needed - and possibly change that name (e.g., something like `ResetBlueChannel()`). There's no point in copying colors that you don't change to set them back right after (yes, all right, it's an example...). I suggest to make a copy of the original Image, with a `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, manipulate and return the copy, leaving the original unchanged.

Comment: Unless you really want to modify the original, that is :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not return anything from a thread start (only void)

```
public Bitmap GetSet(object bmp) ...

public Bitmap LockBits(object bmp) ...
```

These methods can not be used for a ParameterizedThreadStart

You can Invoke Methods on The Main Thread

Put something like this in your Method

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => THIS WILL RUN ON MAIN THREAD));
```